# clang-format not to align virtual function assignment

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is it possible to get clang-format to align consecutive assignments, but at the same time not align  `= 0` pure virtual function markers, i.e.

```cpp
class A
{
   virtual void a() = 0;
   virtual void aaaaaaaaaa() = 0;    // not aligned

   int b     = 0;
   int bbbbb = 0;                    // aligned
};
```

Comment: Have you tried https://clang-format-configurator.site/ ?